# Issue with running my Node JS program on a cloud server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Sorry for such a basic question, however I'm just starting out with javascript programming.

I've got a simple CRUD application working on my laptop using HTMl, Tailwind CSS, Node JS & Express.

After installing the code, Node JS and the required Node Modules on a cloud server (Digital Ocean), I'm getting the following runtime error message:

> node server.js

```
file:///root/BCM_Demo/server.js:114
const myObj = await Fs.readJson('translation.json')
              ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
```

I'd appreciate any advice that you could provide to overcome this issue.

Thanks.

Tried researching the problem, but no joy I'm afraid.

Comment: what version of Node JS?

Comment: Are you creating `const myObj` inside a function marked as `async` ?

Comment: @jQueeny - thanks. I'm using a common Node Module (@supercharge)                   
// Import JSON file and parse it
import Fs from '@supercharge/fs'
const myObj = await Fs.readJson('translation.json')

Comment: @JaromandaX - thanks. I'm running Node JS v12.22.9

Comment: You need to update your Node version. Top level await didn't recieve full support in Node until V14. The current LTS version is 18 so you really should upgrade.

Comment: Got it @jQueeny. Many thanks